# Projecting ngTemplate inside ngTemplate

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component called `ViewEditor` in which I render another component called  which takes a template ref that is rendered in an ngTemplateOutlet. I want to pass a template into ViewEditor and then pass down this template to the shared-field. How is this possible?

I have this but it does not work:

View Editor Component:
[image]
[image]

Shared Field Component:

[image]
[image]

AppComponent:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This kinds of error are mostly because a recursive call don't met a condition to stop.
In this case you're trying to display templates recursively but I don't se a condition to stop

[image]

Note that you're using the parent template ref (field) that host the ng-container where the projection is going to take place. It's like you want to show the table inside of one of the headers cell.
This replicates recursively and never ends.